# Stop keyboard dismissal from resetting the view's height

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I'm making a login screen in iOS 8 using Storyboard (Xcode6 beta7). Here's an image of the basic idea:

[image]

Pressing inside any of the textfields brings up the keyboard, and pressing outside any of them dismisses it again using:

```
self.view.endEditing(true)
```

So pressing the login button makes the keyboard disappear.

When the user enters invalid login credentials I want the dialog view to increase in height and show some error message:

[image]

I'm doing this with an animation using the following function:

```
func increaseHeight(view: UIView, increment: CGFloat) {

    UIView.animateWithDuration(1.0,
        delay: 0.0,
        usingSpringWithDamping: 0.3,
        initialSpringVelocity: 3.0,
        options: UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveEaseInOut,
        animations: ({
            view.frame = CGRect(
                x: view.frame.origin.x,
                y: view.frame.origin.y,
                width: view.frame.width,
                height: view.frame.height + increment
            )
        }),
        completion: nil
    )
}
```

If I invoke this function, let's say by pressing the login button, it's all working as I want. The animation is performed and the error message is shown.

**To the the problem**

However, if I first start to edit any of the textfields (i.e. bringing the keyboard up) and then press the login button, the animation is performed – but it bounces back to its original height.

How can I make the height increment persist after the keyboard has been dismissed?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using auto-layout you need to change constraints not frame of the view.

```
heightOfViewConstraint.constant += increment

UIView animation....{
    self.layoutIfNeeded()
}
```

This should keep your view stretched, but only if you are using auto-layout and constraints.